# "error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file" while executing oald8 binary

Tags: shared-library

I installed `oald8` on Linux 64-bit,on Debian.

At first I installed:

```
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 dpkg-dev
```

Then go to `oald8` and run:

```
linux32 ./setup.sh
```

I setup successfully....

Now I need to install `libglib1.2ldbl` and `libgtk1.2` packages, but unfortunately they have been deprecated.

When I run `oal8`, I get the following error:

```
./oald8-bin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Above error related to the given packages.

I didn't any problem on i386.

By the way, I followed [this](https://nikunjlahoti.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/51/) documentation.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: what do you mean with "Linux 64-bit, not canonical"? what is your system?? (obviously you are running on `amd64`, but what is your distribution?)

Comment: updated my post: Debian.

Comment: What's the output of `ldd ./oald8-bin`?

Comment: A set of packages are related to `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => **not found**` and They're same two packages i expalin in my post,

Answer (score 1):

You are missing at least one (probably more) dependencies on your system.
e.g. for `libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` you need to install the `libgtk2.0-0` package.

To find out which packages in your release provide a given file, use the search at the bottom of https://packages.debian.org.

However, it seems that you are trying to install a 32bit binary on a 64bit system. you might need to enable [multi-arch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) support for the `i386` architecture, and make sure that the dependency packages you install are for the correct arch.

Comment: Before I try it, But i have been installed the given package, the given tutrial mentioned to 32bit packages.